# InnoDB cluster error: ReferenceError: cluster is not defined

Tags: mysql, mysql-innodb-cluster

I was setting up the MySQL InnoDB cluster, when I got this error. I created the cluster from the primary node, the `cluster.status()` was giving output as `'ONLINE'` at this point with only one node part of the cluster (all good till here). But when I tried adding a node in the cluster I got the error:

> "Cluster.addInstance: Cannot add an instance with the same server
>   UUID (db3fdca5-3e67-11e9-98d3-42010a940021) of an active member of the
>   cluster '10.148.0.38:3306'. Please change the se rver UUID of the
>   instance to add, all members must have a unique server UUID.
>   (RuntimeError)"

To resolve this error, I edited the auto.conf and restarted the second instance (did not touch the primary instance at all) Now if I try to check the cluster status (or any commands like `cluster.addInstance()`) I get the same error as given in the title.

Answer (score 0):

The auto.cnf file is automatically generated, you cannot modify this file.

In order to change the UUID, you must delete auto.cnf and restart the MySQL Server. MySQL will generate a new UUID and store it in a new auto.cnf file.

Please check the following documentation section: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options.html#sysvar_server_uuid

Cheers,

Miguel